# Can't register dll using WiX - error code "hresult -2147024770"

Tags: c++, wix, windows-10, ime, regsvr32

I am developing an IME (Input Method Editor) for Windows so I compiled this sample from microsoft: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Input-Method-Editor-IME-b1610980/view/Discussions/1 using Visual Studio 2015 and packaged it using WiX.
It installs fine on the computer on which I compiled it, but it seems like I cannot get regsvr32 to register the dll/ime on my other computer (both running windows 10).  I get this error

[image: I get this error]

, and manually registering the dll through cmd doesn't work either.  My guess is that I am missing a dependency?  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Here is the .wxs packaging code from WiX:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="WiXSetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="lwrnc" UpgradeCode="5973bdd3-dea7-4924-a303-4e881386e030">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />    
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WiXSetup" Level="1">            
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="StartMenuComponents" />
      <!--<ComponentGroupRef Id="IMEComponentsx86" />-->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="IMEComponentsx64" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

  <!--Directory Structure-->
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">             
      <!--Start Menu Shortcut-->
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyShortcutsDir" Name="WiXSetup">          
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <!--x86 Version-->
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="IMEINSTALLFOLDERx86" Name="WiXSetup">          
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <!--x64 Version-->
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="IMEINSTALLFOLDERx64" Name="WiXSetup">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>  

  <!--Components-->
    <Fragment>  

    <!--x86 IME-->
    <!--<ComponentGroup Id="IMEComponentsx86" Directory="IMEINSTALLFOLDERx86">
      <Component Id="CMP_IMEx86" Guid="{0CB17F8D-26FF-4E29-A428-710791CDE1EB}">
        <File Id="FILE_IMEINSTALLFOLDER_SampleIMEx86DLL" Source="SampleIMEx86.dll" KeyPath="yes" SelfRegCost="1" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_DICTx86" Guid="{66474BE0-ABE5-4B22-8F9B-EB894C6A6218}">
        <File Id="FILE_IMEINSTALLFOLDER_SampleIMESimplifiedQuanPinx86TXT" Source="SampleIMESimplifiedQuanPin.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>-->

    <!--x64 IME-->
    <ComponentGroup Id="IMEComponentsx64" Directory="IMEINSTALLFOLDERx64">
      <Component Id="CMP_IMEx64" Guid="{AEDC5FB8-6BB9-4A9F-B920-D6D8244BB837}">
        <File Id="FILE_IMEINSTALLFOLDER_SampleIMEx64DLL" Source="SampleIMEx64.dll" KeyPath="yes" SelfRegCost="1" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_DICT" Guid="{C555385F-4848-48B4-90A8-EB0E722605EB}">
        <File Id="FILE_IMEINSTALLFOLDER_SampleIMESimplifiedQuanPinx64TXT" Source="SampleIMESimplifiedQuanPin.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <!--Start Menu Components-->
    <ComponentGroup Id="StartMenuComponents" Directory="MyShortcutsDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_DocumentationShortcut" Guid="{4EFD00CD-2297-4A9D-A0A5-47C26897E223}">
        <Shortcut Id="WiXSetupDoc" Name="WiXSetup Doc" Description="Read this please" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]lwrnc.txt" />        
        <Shortcut Id="UninstallShortcut" Name="Uninstall WS" Description="uninstall wixsetup practice" Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMyShortcutsDir" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\WiXSetup" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>            
    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find which dependent module(s) are missing?

Comment: I have, but I don't know what to make of this:  http://imgur.com/a/n77Fd

Comment: I also have Microsoft Visual CC++ redistributable for 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010 installed